# ошибка SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

Начал заниматься питоном месяц назад. Решил сделать что-то.
Но возникла проблема SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.
Я немного почитал про эту ошибку, все скобки вроде на месте.
вот код:

```
def check(comm):
    comm = str(comm)
    commlist = comm.split(' ')
    if commlist[0] == 'get':
        print('-> ' + commlist[1])

while True:
    comm = input('<- ')
    check(comm)
```

**Помогите пожалуйста!**

Comment: В какой строчке?

Comment: @Эникейщик <- get hello>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amirv/PycharmProjects/untitled1/index.py", line 8, in <module>
    comm = input('<- ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    get hello>
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: У меня нет такой ошибки

Comment: Это может быть связано с кодировкой?

Comment: Это может быть связано с вашим скриптом целиком. Указанный фрагмент может не содержать ошибки, а весь скрипт - запросто.

Comment: фишка в том что это и есть весь скрипт целиком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки у вас две. Во-первых, вы зачем-то используете Python2. Во-вторых, используете `input` вместо `raw_input`.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел в настройки, а там стоит python 2. Поменял на третий все заработало!